# Trying to replace battery pack with dedicated power supply

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging

I have a touch sensitive sink faucet that runs on 6 AA batteries. I'd like to replace the AAs with rechargeable 18650 batteries and also connect a power supply to power the faucet, but also keep the batteries charged for power outages.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would be hesitant to have a tap connected in any way to the powerline

Comment: You might look into wireless charging devices to avoid direct connection to a power line connected charger, but it would be fairly safe with a wall-wart type charger plugged into a GFCI outlet.

Comment: I was considering the safety issue of electricity and water pipe/faucet.  If the voltage supplied to faucet solenoid is low voltage and DC I'm not seeing a potential for electrocution.  I may just go the route of replacing the 6 AA's with 3 rechargable 18650's.